# A simple POST request to Web API not hitting the API at all

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

From my MVC application, I am trying to make a POST request to these sample end-points (actions) in an API controller named `MembershipController`:

```
[HttpPost]
public string GetFoo([FromBody]string foo)
{
    return string.Concat("This is foo: ", foo);
}

[HttpPost]
public string GetBar([FromBody]int bar)
{
    return string.Concat("This is bar: ", bar.ToString());
}

[HttpPost]
public IUser CreateNew([FromBody]NewUserAccountInfo newUserAccountInfo)
{
    return new User();
}
```

Here's the client code:

```
var num = new WebAPIClient().PostAsXmlAsync<int, string>("api/membership/GetBar", 4).Result;
```

And here's the code for my `WebAPIClient` class:

```
public class WebAPIClient
{
    private string _baseUri = null;

    public WebAPIClient()
    {
        // TO DO: Make this configurable
        _baseUri = "http://localhost:54488/";
    }

    public async Task<R> PostAsXmlAsync<T, R>(string uri, T value)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseUri);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

            var requestUri = new Uri(client.BaseAddress, uri);

            var response = await client.PostAsXmlAsync<T>(requestUri, value);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var taskOfR = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<R>();

            return taskOfR;
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following default route defined for the Web API:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

**UPDATE**
My code breaks into the debugger until the time the `PostAsXmlAsync` method on the `System.Net.HttpClient` code is called. However, no request shows up in Fiddler.

However, if I try to compose a POST request in Fiddler or try to fire a GET request via the browser to one of the API end-points, the POST request composed via Fiddler tells me that I am not sending any data and that I must. The browser sent GET request rightly tells me that the action does not support a GET request.

It just seems like the `System.Net.HttpClient` class is not sending the POST request properly.

Comment: Can you show what your POST request that's not working looks like?

Comment: Fiddler doesn't capture localhost traffic by default. You must do something for it to capture this traffic: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/MonitorLocalTraffic

Comment: You can use a chrome extension like Postman, DHC or Advanced REST client, to test your Web API. Try any of them, they are extremely helpful, and making requests is somewhat easier that using Fiddler. (I prefer Postman: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en ).

Comment: This is a long time ago but I'm literally having the exact same problem almost word for word, did you ever solve this?

Comment: @NardDog: I can't remember but I think it was that my Newtonsoft.Json library wasn't loaded correctly in my client application and I had to update it. I got to know by putting a try/catch and chasing every `InnerException` that was nested in the main exception tree.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most usual problems is that you don't use the appropriate attribute.

Take into account that there are attributes for ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web API with the same name, but which live in different namespaces:

- [For Web API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httppostattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) you must use the one in `System.Web.Http`
- [For MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httppostattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), the one in `System.Web.MVc`

This is a very very usual error, and it affects to allkind of things that exist for both MVC and Web API. So you must be very careful when using something which can exists in bith worlds (for example filters, attributes, or dependency injection registration).

Comment: Thank you. That's very useful advise. I just checked and the attributes are all coming from the right place, i.e. from the `System.Web.Http` namespace in the Web API.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem (may not be same one though). In my case, I hadn't given name attribute to the input element. I only figured that out when fiddler showed no post data being sent to the server (just like your case)

```
<input id="test" name="xyz" type="text" />
```

Adding the name attribute in the input tag fixed my problem.

However, there is one more thing to note. WebAPI does not put form data into parameters directly. Either you have to create an object with those properties and put that object in the parameter of the post controller. Or you could put no parameters at all like this:

```
    [Route("name/add")]

    public async Task Post()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            return;
        }

        var provider = PostHelper.GetMultipartProvider();
        var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
        var clientId = result.FormData["xyz"];
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the FromBody to FromUri.

If the parameter is a "simple" type, Web API tries to get the value from the URI. Simple types include the .NET primitive types (int, bool, double, and so forth), plus TimeSpan, DateTime, Guid, decimal, and string, plus any type with a type converter that can convert from a string.

For complex types, Web API tries to read the value from the message body, using a media-type formatter.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `FromBody` at all and don't make any restrictions in passing parameters (it can be passed at this time either in uri, query string or form submissions (which is kinda a similar to query strings)

```
[HttpPost]
public string GetFoo(string foo){...}
```

It will be implicitly parsed and passed.